# Internal implementation of HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, hash-function

I am trying to create the data structure of a `HashMap()` in Java. The HashMap has to work for a maximum of `N = 1000` operations and the keys are only positive integers. What I did is the following:

```
class MyHashMap {
        final ListNode[] nodes = new ListNode[1000];
        // "put", "get" and "remove" methods which take
        // collisions into account using "chaining".
}
```

to decide the placement of my new key - value pair in `nodes` I always need to compute an index. I use the function:

```
 public int getIndex(int key) { return Integer.hashCode(key) % nodes.length;}
```

which returns an integer between `0` and `nodes.length`. But how can I write a Hashfunction in Java on my own that maps integers to some index without using `Integer.hashMap(key)`?
Also the procedure is fine, I don't really need a code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple strategy for hashing an `int` value is to multiply by a large constant. If you don't use a constant, you can get very poor collision rates depending on your key distribution. It's is still possible to get poor key distribution, however it is less likely for real data.

NOTE: Unless you know the key cannot be negative, you should use `Math.abs` to ensure it is non-negative.

```
static final int K = 0x7A646E4D; // some large prime.

public int getIndex(int key) { 
    return Math.abs(key * K % nodes.length);
}
```

A faster solution is to drop the use of `%` use a multiplication and shift. e.g.

```
public int getIndex(int key) { 
    return (int) ((key * K & 0xFFFF_FFFFL) * nodes.length >>> 32);
}
```

What this does is turn `key * K` into a fraction and is faster than using `%`

Comment: Seems like you first take the lowest 32 bits after multiplication, and in the end you use only the upper 32 bits?

Comment: do you maybe know where these things are explained ? e.g. how to hash an integer, a string ecc.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik In the second example, I start with the lower bits of a 64-bit value which after shifting by 32-bits at the end, act like a fraction.

Comment: @Giacomo all data are numbers. You either have a single value like `int` or an array or values like `char[]` which will require a loop but the principles are the same.

Comment: I see now. You use the 32-bit number as a scale factor which is effectively in the range (0,1).

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.hashCode(key)` just returns `key` as result. You could write:

```
public int getIndex(int key) { 
    return key % nodes.length;
}
```

This way, you don't use `Integer.hashCode(key)`.

Without seeing your class `ListNode`, you could have a problem with your `MyHashMap` structure since you are setting many elements to the same array element. For instance the key `3` and `1003` will be saved in the same node element. You must design `MyHashMap` to be a list of list (or an array of list or something similar).

Comment: Maybe my question what not so clear. Doing it like I did, Integer.hashCode(key) will return an Integer value which can be everything. Taking % nodes.length this will ensure that this value has now a number which is in the range of my array nodes. If I get a value which corresponds to a cell which is already occupied, I will create (in my methods, this can not be seen in the question) a link to a new node to prevent the collision. So I don't really have the problem you are mentioning.

Comment: Well you must still consider the collisions since they are possible. Of course there is hash function which reduces the collisions, but it was not in your question.

Comment: @Giacomo Note: `-1 % nodes.length == -1`

Comment: @PeterLawrey i did not mention that keys are potive integers, need to edit it

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all the `hash` is something that is unique or a very rarely repeating value.

Assuming that your values will be evenly distributed you can use the remainder of division as a hash value for your key.

```
public int get(int key) {
    return (-1 ^ key) % nodes.length;
}
```

Comment: Note: if `key` is negative, this can return a negative number.